# Magento 2 graphql get the cms block based on store

Tags: cms, magento2.3.3, cms-block, graphql

I am trying to get the cms block based on store, but it is alway returning the default store block content.

The query I used :

```
{
  cmsBlocks(identifiers: "login-data") {
    items {
      identifier
      title
      content
    }
  }
}
```

The above one is not giving block content based on the store I set in HTTP HEADER!!

I saw the cms block resolver and did not find any store-based cms block fetch

```
vendor/magento/module-cms-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/Blocks.php
```

Comment: which type of store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue please apply below Patch (feel free to give your thoughts to improve the solution):

```
**FOR MAGENTO 2.3.3**

Index: vendor/magento/module-cms-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/DataProvider/Block.php
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- /vendor/magento/module-cms-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/DataProvider/Block.php   (date 1579789952704)
+++ /vendor/magento/module-cms-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/DataProvider/Block.php   (date 1579789952704)
@@ -11,6 +11,8 @@
 use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
 use Magento\Widget\Model\Template\FilterEmulate;
+use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
+use Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifierInterface as BlockGetter;

 /**
  * Cms block data provider
@@ -33,10 +35,14 @@
      */
     public function __construct(
         BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
-        FilterEmulate $widgetFilter
+        FilterEmulate $widgetFilter,
+        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
+        BlockGetter $BlockGetter
     ) {
         $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
         $this->widgetFilter = $widgetFilter;
+        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
+        $this->blockGetter = $BlockGetter;
     }

     /**
@@ -48,22 +54,25 @@
      */
     public function getData(string $blockIdentifier): array
     {
-        $block = $this->blockRepository->getById($blockIdentifier);
-
+        /* start custom code changes to get cms based on store */
+        $storeId  = (int)$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
+        $block = $this->blockGetter->execute($blockIdentifier, $storeId);
+        /* end custom code changes to get cms based on store */
         if (false === $block->isActive()) {
             throw new NoSuchEntityException(
                 __('The CMS block with the "%1" ID doesn\'t exist.', $blockIdentifier)
             );
         }
-
-        $renderedContent = $this->widgetFilter->filter($block->getContent());
-
-        $blockData = [
-            BlockInterface::BLOCK_ID => $block->getId(),
-            BlockInterface::IDENTIFIER => $block->getIdentifier(),
-            BlockInterface::TITLE => $block->getTitle(),
-            BlockInterface::CONTENT => $renderedContent,
-        ];
-        return $blockData;
-    }
-}
+        if($block->getIdentifier() == $blockIdentifier) {
+            $renderedContent = $this->widgetFilter->filter($block->getContent());
+            $blockData = [
+                BlockInterface::BLOCK_ID => $block->getId(),
+                BlockInterface::IDENTIFIER => $block->getIdentifier(),
+                BlockInterface::TITLE => $block->getTitle(),
+                BlockInterface::CONTENT => $renderedContent,
+            ];
+            return $blockData;
+        }
+        return '';
+    }
+}
\ No newline at end of file
```

**FOR MAGENTO 2.3.4**

```
Index: /vendor/magento/module-cms-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/DataProvider/Block.php
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- /vendor/magento/module-cms-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/DataProvider/Block.php   (date 1579875025862)
+++ /vendor/magento/module-cms-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/DataProvider/Block.php   (date 1579875025862)
@@ -11,6 +11,8 @@
 use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
 use Magento\Widget\Model\Template\FilterEmulate;
+use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
+use Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifierInterface as BlockGetter;

 /**
  * Cms block data provider
@@ -30,13 +32,19 @@
     /**
      * @param BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository
      * @param FilterEmulate $widgetFilter
+     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
+     * @param BlockGetter $BlockGetter
      */
     public function __construct(
         BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
-        FilterEmulate $widgetFilter
+        FilterEmulate $widgetFilter,
+        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
+        BlockGetter $BlockGetter
     ) {
         $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
         $this->widgetFilter = $widgetFilter;
+        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
+        $this->blockGetter = $BlockGetter;
     }

     /**
@@ -48,7 +56,10 @@
      */
     public function getData(string $blockIdentifier): array
     {
-        $block = $this->blockRepository->getById($blockIdentifier);
+        /* start custom code changes to get cms based on store */
+        $storeId = (int)$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
+        $block = $this->blockGetter->execute($blockIdentifier, $storeId);
+        /* end custom code changes to get cms based on store */

         if (false === $block->isActive()) {
             throw new NoSuchEntityException(
@@ -57,13 +68,16 @@
         }

         $renderedContent = $this->widgetFilter->filterDirective($block->getContent());
-
-        $blockData = [
-            BlockInterface::BLOCK_ID => $block->getId(),
-            BlockInterface::IDENTIFIER => $block->getIdentifier(),
-            BlockInterface::TITLE => $block->getTitle(),
-            BlockInterface::CONTENT => $renderedContent,
-        ];
-        return $blockData;
+        if ($block->getIdentifier() == $blockIdentifier) {
+            $blockData = [
+                BlockInterface::BLOCK_ID => $block->getId(),
+                BlockInterface::IDENTIFIER => $block->getIdentifier(),
+                BlockInterface::TITLE => $block->getTitle(),
+                BlockInterface::CONTENT => $renderedContent,
+            ];
+            return $blockData;
+        }else{
+            return [];
+        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Fixing this issue update file

Magento\CmsGraphQl\Model\Resolver\DataProvider\Block.php with below code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magento\CmsGraphQl\Model\Resolver\DataProvider;

use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Widget\Model\Template\FilterEmulate;

/**
 * Cms block data provider
 */
class Block
{
    /**
     * @var BlockRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $blockRepository;

    /**
     * @var FilterEmulate
     */
    private $widgetFilter;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository
     * @param FilterEmulate $widgetFilter
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        FilterEmulate $widgetFilter,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder = null,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
        $this->widgetFilter = $widgetFilter;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder ?: \Magento\Framework
            \App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: \Magento\Framework
            \App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get block data
     *
     * @param string $blockIdentifier
     * @return array
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getData(string $blockIdentifier): array
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('identifier', $blockIdentifier, 'eq')
            ->addFilter('store_id', $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(), 'eq')
            ->addFilter('is_active', true, 'eq')->create();
        $block = current($this->blockRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems());

        if (empty($block)) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(
                __('The CMS block with the "%1" ID doesn\'t exist.', $blockIdentifier)
            );
        }

        $renderedContent = $this->widgetFilter->filterDirective($block->getContent());

        $blockData = [
            BlockInterface::BLOCK_ID => $block->getId(),
            BlockInterface::IDENTIFIER => $block->getIdentifier(),
            BlockInterface::TITLE => $block->getTitle(),
            BlockInterface::CONTENT => $renderedContent,
        ];
        return $blockData;
    }
}
```